# tomee jaxws security with public WSDL

Tags: security, jax-ws, apache-tomee

I use the Tomee+ (Version 1.6.0) and deployed my webservice via ear archive (apps directory). some methods(not all) of my webservice have a RolesAllowed Annotation.

My Clients needs to access the WSDL without authentication but tomee request one. So i filled in (for test cases) username and password but access is denied. I found out that it requries the role "default" but i never configured such a role.

is there a way to secure some methods and make the WSDL public accessable?

Answer (score 0):

WSDL has the same constraint as the webservice itself (as in cxf), you'll need to either do a custom security interceptor to let wsdl requests pass or just cache the wsdl in the webapp and expose it as a resource.